# How can I create groups that have similar totals using pandas, numpy, or itertools?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-itertools

What is the best way to create n groups of n size that have a similar total file size given a DataFrame with a column for files and file sizes? While searching, this problem sounded similar to the knapsack problem, except there are no hard stops. Any solution that is quick and produces groups of any length that are close to average (be it under or over) would be a great improvement.

My first attempt (t1) creates groups by counting in a circular order. Next attempt (t2),  sorts the DataFrame by size in hopes of preventing one group from getting a clump of large files, but the approach is basically the same as t1.  There are usually ~300 files total. In this context, I was not sure if it is practical to calculate all possible combinations or if there is a better approach.

```
from itertools import repeat, chain
from math import ceil
import pandas as pd

source_dict = {'file_name_': {0: 'file_0', 1: 'file_1', 2: 'file_2', 3: 'file_3', 4: 'file_4', 5: 'file_5', 6: 'file_6', 7: 'file_7', 8: 'file_8', 9: 'file_9'
                              , 10: 'file_10', 11: 'file_11', 12: 'file_12', 13: 'file_13', 14: 'file_14', 15: 'file_15', 16: 'file_16', 17: 'file_17', 18: 'file_18'
                              , 19: 'file_19', 20: 'file_20', 21: 'file_21', 22: 'file_22', 23: 'file_23', 24: 'file_24', 25: 'file_25', 26: 'file_26', 27: 'file_27'
                              , 28: 'file_28', 29: 'file_29', 30: 'file_30', 31: 'file_31', 32: 'file_32', 33: 'file_33', 34: 'file_34', 35: 'file_35', 36: 'file_36'
                              , 37: 'file_37', 38: 'file_38', 39: 'file_39', 40: 'file_40', 41: 'file_41', 42: 'file_42', 44: 'file_44', 45: 'file_45', 46: 'file_46'
                              , 47: 'file_47', 48: 'file_48', 49: 'file_49', 50: 'file_50'}
               , 'file_size': {0: 3407245, 1: 3973920, 2: 7408640, 3: 4086426, 4: 12795600, 5: 2155039, 6: 9514856, 7: 13190235, 8: 32043703, 9: 4936240, 10: 9591964
                               , 11: 70153435, 12: 5106282, 13: 212414, 14: 24998146, 15: 11605646, 16: 2427516, 17: 23634036, 18: 169983, 19: 7011305, 20: 2106828
                               , 21: 3420304, 22: 11254, 23: 1271220, 24: 1164562, 25: 83613105, 26: 1030701, 27: 366948, 28: 7014895, 29: 8274642, 30: 2731629
                               , 31: 1596299, 32: 524, 33: 302, 34: 42332100, 35: 5441036, 36: 40633457, 37: 34680208, 38: 123505, 39: 15905009, 40: 52071678
                               , 41: 10624966, 42: 15425993, 44: 27673986, 45: 144988223, 46: 62619919, 47: 21562386, 48: 10620299, 49: 254661, 50: 232406680}}


sampleSizesDF = pd.DataFrame(source_dict)

desired_groups = 4 # multiprocessing.cpu_count()

group_size = ceil(sampleSizesDF.file_name_.count() / desired_groups) 

max_length = sampleSizesDF.file_name_.count() # upper bound for list

# trial 1, count off and group
my_groups = list(chain(*repeat(list(range(0,desired_groups)), group_size)))[:max_length]

sampleSizesDF['pGroup_t1'] = my_groups

# trial 2, sort + trial 1
sampleSizesDF.sort_values('file_size', inplace = True)

sampleSizesDF['pGroup_t2'] = my_groups
```

```
pGroupDistDF = pd.concat([
                              sampleSizesDF.groupby('pGroup_t1').agg({'file_size': 'sum'})
                            , sampleSizesDF.groupby('pGroup_t2').agg({'file_size': 'sum'})
                         ]
                         , axis=1)

pGroupDistDF.columns = ['t1', 't2']

pGroupDistDF = pGroupDistDF.merge(pd.DataFrame(pGroupDistDF.values, columns=['t1_dist', 't2_dist']).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum()), left_index=True, right_index=True)

presentation_order = ['t1', 't1_dist', 't2', 't2_dist']

pGroupDistDF[presentation_order]


    t1          t1_dist     t2          t2_dist
0   304015174   0.281916    291719748   0.270514
1   470551775   0.436347    396619142   0.367788
2   134901157   0.125095    183490246   0.170152
3   168921844   0.156643    206560814   0.191546
```